# C++ circular reference problem

Tags: c++, class-design, destructor, circular-dependency, forward-declaration

I have 2 classes: `DataObject` and `DataElement`. `DataObject` holds pointers to (only) `DataElement`s, and a `DataElement` contains pointers to several types, among which a `DataObject`.

This used to be no problem, since I only use pointers to `DataObject`s in `DataElement`, so a forward declaration of `DataObject` in the header of `DataElement` is enough.

Now, however, I try to add a destructor to `DataElement`, in which I need a delete on a `DataObject`. On this the compiler says:

```
dataelement/destructor.cc: In destructor ‘DataElement::~DataElement()’:
dataelement/destructor.cc:8: warning: possible problem detected in invocation of delete operator:
dataelement/destructor.cc:8: warning: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct DataObject’
dataelement/dataelement.h:7: warning: forward declaration of ‘struct DataObject’
dataelement/destructor.cc:8: note: neither the destructor nor the class-specific operator delete will be called, even if they are declared when the class is defined.
```

How can I solve this? A forward declaration is apparently not enough, while I cannot include the complete header for `DataObject`, since that gives me a circular dependency again.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider using a smart pointer like `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr`, `scoped_ptr`, or `unique_ptr` (if your implementation supports it); these make resource management in C++ much, much easier and help you to ensure that you code is exception safe and correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the destructor in a .cpp file that includes both headers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. (now I know the solution its sooo obvious, but thats always afterwards :) )

Answer (score 2):

Make the destructor for the first class defined outside of the class body and after the second class, e.g.

```
class DataElement;

class DataObject
{
    DataElement* elem;
public:
    ~DataObject();
};

class DataElement
{
    DataObject* obj;
public:
    ~DataElement() { delete obj; }
};

DataObject::~DataObject()
{
    delete elem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll go for the solution of James McNellis since it is easier to do right now, but this seems also a good solution.