# How do i use an array of a different class in a class?

Tags: c++

Town.h

```
class Town;
```

Tailor.h

```
#include "Town.h"
class Bully;
#include "Bully.h"
class Tailor
{
  public:
    //LookAround is called only in randWalk
    void lookAround(Town & town, const short direction, const Bully bully[]);
    //THIS is the code inside randwalk that calls bully 
    if(!bully[0].punch(*this,town))

    void randWalk(Town & town, const Bully bully[]);
  private:
}
```

Bully.h

```
#include "Town.h"
class Tailor;
#include "Tailor.h"
class Bully
{
  public:
    bool punch(Tailor& tailor, Town & town);
  private:
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Town.h"
#include "Tailor.h"
#include "Bully.h"

int main()
{
  const char PLAYER_NAME[] = "Milhouse";

  Bully bully_team[5];

  //create a town
  Town r(10,40,25);

  //create a Tailor player called PLAYER_NAME and place him at 2,3
  Tailor player(PLAYER_NAME);
  player.placeMe(r);

  //make the character move 12 times
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    player.randWalk(r, bully_team);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I need access to an array of type Bully in a Player function, but Bully needs type Player to function. This Bully array needs to be declared in main. I have been trying many different ways of forwarding classes, but i can't seem to get it work.

```
In file included from Tailor.h:8:0,
                 from main.cpp:7:
Bully.h:43:17: error: 'MAX_NAME_LENGTH' was not declared in this scope
     char m_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
                 ^
Bully.h: In function 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Bully&)':
Bully.h:31:33: error: 'const class Bully' has no member named 'm_name'
       int length = strlen(bully.m_name);
                                 ^
Bully.h:35:23: error: 'const class Bully' has no member named 'm_name'
         cout << bully.m_name[i];
                       ^
In file included from Tailor.h:8:0,
                 from Tailor.cpp:1:
Bully.h:43:17: error: 'MAX_NAME_LENGTH' was not declared in this scope
     char m_name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
                 ^
Bully.h: In function 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Bully&)':
Bully.h:31:33: error: 'const class Bully' has no member named 'm_name'
       int length = strlen(bully.m_name);
                                 ^
Bully.h:35:23: error: 'const class Bully' has no member named 'm_name'
         cout << bully.m_name[i];
                       ^
Tailor.cpp: In member function 'void Tailor::lookAround(Town&, short int, const Bully*)':
Tailor.cpp:70:34: error: passing 'const Bully' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
     if(!bully[0].punch(*this,town))
                                  ^
In file included from Tailor.h:8:0,
                 from Tailor.cpp:1:
Bully.h:27:10: note:   in call to 'bool Bully::punch(Tailor&, Town&)'
     bool punch(Tailor& tailor, Town & town);
          ^
```

Comment: You'll need to use pointers, then you can use forward definitions.

Comment: So you need to make it an array of `Bully*` in `Player`.

Comment: Similar if not dupe: [Circular Dependency in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018816/circular-dependency-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular Dependency in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018816/circular-dependency-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Use this order:

1. Declare `Player` and `Bully`
2. Define `Player` and `Bully`
3. Define the functions of `Player` and `Bully` and `main`

The order within 2. may be significant. Only one of `Player` and `Bully` can depend on the definition of the other, and that dependency determines which must be defined after the other. The one that doesn't have a dependency must at most depend on the declaration of the other. Declaring a function that takes a pointer to an array does not require the definition of the pointed type, so `Player` apparently doesn't depend on the definition of `Bully`.

The order within 1. and 3. is not significant, and each of the functions may be defined in separate translation unit (source file) if you so wish.